# Trying to call a SQL package function from ADF

Tags: java, sql, oracle-adf

I have the following function in a package I need to call from java code in ADF

```
FUNCTION COPY_ITEM(O_error_message        IN OUT    VARCHAR2,
                     I_master_order   IN        FFE_ITEM.MASTER_ORDER%TYPE,
                     I_item           IN        FFE_ITEM.ITEM%TYPE,
                     O_new_item       OUT       FFE_ITEM.ITEM%TYPE)
return NUMBER;
```

Here is the code I am trying to call it with

```
        String stmt = "FFE_CREATE_ITEM.COPY_ITEM(?,?,?,?)";
        cst = this.getDBTransaction().createCallableStatement("begin ? := " + stmt + ";end;", 0);
        //Register dataType for return value
        cst.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        cst.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NUMERIC);
        cst.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
        cst.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);

        cst.setObject(2 , errorO);
        cst.setObject(3 , orderNum);
        cst.setObject(4 , itemNum);
        cst.setObject(5 , newItemNum);

        cst.executeUpdate();
```

But I keep getting a oracle.jbo.JboException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index 1 error.

Not really sure what I am doing wrong, any tips would be great. I think I have not registered the return value but not sure how to do this.

Comment: Just call `cst.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);` ? Why do you call that with 2,3,4,5 and not with 1,2,3,4 ?

Comment: Im still not entirely sure how to do this. You need to register and out for the return, then register the other out? can you provide some code samples?

Comment: Why do you start with `cst.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);`? Why `2` and not `1`?